# Sending Username and password to web service using json

Tags: javascript, json, html

Hi i would like to create a login page in html 5, but in order to login i need to send the username and password to a web service, the web service is already created and it will return a value 0 if flase and any other number if true. I can only use javascript and json. Can anyone help me out to understand json as i know almost nothing about it. How would i send the username and password using json and javascript?

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific thing that's hanging you up? You get better answers when you have specific questions and code showing what you've done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var form;

form.onsubmit = function (e) {
  // stop the regular form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
  var data = {};
  for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
      data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }

  // construct an HTTP request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

  // send the collected data as JSON
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };
};
```

Comment: I am new to html 5 as my company just asked me to create this with this requirements. I personally only know c# and vb. I created the login page in html and that is as far as i have done

Comment: may I recommand yu a tutorial in HTML 5 ??? if yu have a basic knowledge of HTML, then it will take only an hour for yu to understand it...

go to http://w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Comment: Yes that would be great. Thanks alot i will try out this coding now

Comment: must i just copy and paste it into my javascript page and it will run? sorry lol am new to javascript

Comment: and where do  add the url of the web service?